# How to remove 'NA' in lm summary ouput

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, interpretation

The data I am working with is found here
 http://www.stat.ucla.edu/projects/datasets/

It is the twins data and i downloaded the stata file.

I am performing multiple regression and this is what i have

```
library(foreign)
twin.data=read.dta("twins.dta")

attach(twin.data)
head(twin.data)
twin.data=na.omit(twin.data)
m1=lm(dlhrwage~deduc1+age+agesq+hrwageh+whiteh+maleh+educh+hrwagel+whitel+malel+educl+deduc2+dten+dmarried+duncov)
summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = dlhrwage ~ deduc1 + age + agesq + hrwageh + whiteh + 
maleh + educh + hrwagel + whitel + malel + educl + deduc2 + 
dten + dmarried + duncov)

 Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.66072 -0.18017 -0.04059  0.11919  1.04205 

 Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.087e-01  3.690e-01   1.650 0.101391    
deduc1       4.005e-02  1.896e-02   2.112 0.036522 *  
age         -1.355e-02  1.560e-02  -0.869 0.386628    
agesq        9.995e-05  1.932e-04   0.517 0.605846    
hrwageh      4.521e-02  3.183e-03  14.204  < 2e-16 ***
whiteh      -1.322e-01  1.946e-01  -0.679 0.498151    
maleh       -3.259e-02  5.192e-02  -0.628 0.531299    
educh       -2.886e-02  1.370e-02  -2.107 0.037006 *  
hrwagel     -3.239e-02  2.746e-03 -11.798  < 2e-16 ***
whitel       1.754e-01  2.014e-01   0.871 0.385267    
malel               NA         NA      NA       NA    
educl               NA         NA      NA       NA    
deduc2       1.505e-02  1.656e-02   0.909 0.365160    
dten         1.476e-02  3.741e-03   3.947 0.000128 ***
dmarried     4.486e-02  4.878e-02   0.920 0.359483    
duncov      -1.575e-02  5.399e-02  -0.292 0.770992    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2977 on 133 degrees of freedom
(36 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.7626,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7394 
F-statistic: 32.86 on 13 and 133 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The issue here is the 'NA' showing up for both malel and educ1

MALEL is 1 if twin 1 is male, 0 otherwise. (categorical)

EDUCL is Self-reported education (in years) of twin 1. (numerical)

how do i deal with this?

output of malel is

```
 malel
  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
 [40] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
[79] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  0 1 1
[118] 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[157] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

output of educl is

```
> educl
  [1] 16 10 12 12 14 14 15 14 14 12 13 12 12 19 12 14 16 12 12 12 12 16 12 14 14 12
 [27] 12 14 12 20 12 16 12 11 12 18 18 16 12 14 16 12 16 18 16 13 15 17 16 12 20 14
 [53] 14 12 13 19 13 13 18 16 13 14 18 16 13 12  8 18 14 13 15 16 16 16 14 19 16 12
 [79] 14 12 15 12 12 16 13 16 10 13 12 12 14 12 14 14 16 14 16 12 18 12 16 16 13 16
[105] 12 14 14 16 12 14 16 15 12 13 14 16 15 13 15 10 12 18 12 16 14 14 12 13 15 12
[131] 20 12 14 14 16 16 13 15 16 14 16 12 12 12 12 12 16 12 18 12 12 15 12 12 15 14
[157] 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 16 12 13 13 16 18 12 16 10 13 12 12 12 14 12 16 12 16
[183] 16
```

Comment: Your output gives you a hint: "2 singularities". Could you check whether malel and educl aren't all the same value, or if one of the other contains precisely the same information?

Comment: @iws they arent the same value

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that malel and educl are linear combinations of other predictors.

You can see that $malel=maleh$:

```
> with(twin.data,MALEL-MALEH)
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [38] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [75] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[112] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[149] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And that $educl=educh-deduc1$:

```
> with(twin.data,EDUCL-(EDUCH-DEDUC1))
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [38] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [75] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[112] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[149] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

When predictors are not linearly independent some parameters are undefined. This can only be solved by dropping redundant predictors until all predictors are linearly independent.

And just as and end note: the way to find out linear combinations has been fitting a linear model with the suspected variable as response: `summary(lm(EDUCL~.-DLHRWAGE,data=twin.data))`

---

**Edit about how to "solve" the problem, after comments:**

I'll put an example of the same problem.

Once a herdsman wanted to count the number of cows in his herd. He supposed he could do it by counting numbers of heads, feet and ears in the herd. He tried performing a regression analysis and got parameters 1 for heads and NA for ears and feet. That is, he could count cows just by counting heads.

However, he decided that dropping redundant predictors was a problem and asked for advice to a neighbour who happened to be a mathematician and gave him the method he was looking for: sum the number of heads, feet and ears in the herd and divide the sum by 7 to get the number of cows.

Anyway, please noticed that adding redundant variables hasn't changed the model - it's predictions are exactly the same. The mathematician just made it more complicated.

Therefore, dropping exactly redundant variables is not a problem. It's just sanitising the data.

The problem that ridge regression and Lasso are created to face is collinearity, and it's a different one, because on collinearity redundancy is not exact. Here ridge regression - if it worked - would just be a way to find one of the many infinite estimation of parameters, and not necessarily the best one because ridge regression doesn't shrink parameters to zero. Maybe lasso could drop automatically the redundant parameters because it does shrink parameters to zero.

However, that isn't better than what already does lm function in R: dropping predictors by returning NA as parameter estimate.

Comment: Thanks you! i did a correlation matrix and found these predictors to have high correlations with those they are a linear combination of.

Comment: @ollypop Not exactly. $malel$ and $maleh$ have correlation 1, but $educl$ is not highly correlated with $educh$ and $deduc1$. You can try `with(twin.data,cor(data.frame(MALEL,MALEH,EDUCL,EDUCH,DEDUC1)))`. Moreover, don't miss this problem with collinearity.

Comment: Dropping predictors is not the only solution! The user could also use ridge regression for example.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Would ridge regression also work in this situation, where Pere rightly showed (a combination of two) other predictors contain ***exactly*** the same information?

Comment: Yes, I believe it would.